# CodeIgniter Oauth library

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, twitter

Hey guys Im planning on creating a web application that will use the twitter API. I have searched around the internet and have found several PHP Oauth libraries, everything from the module on the Zend Framework to one person projects on github. They all look great and I would like to try them all, but I don't have the time. So my question is, for those who have experience using a Oauth library with PHP, preferably as a code igniter library. What are the most reliable , well rounded libraries to use? which ones should I stay away from? Please share your experience with PHP and Oauth thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Here's my experience with PHP + Oauth:

1% of time doing fun stuff.  99% of time trying to figure out why signature is invalid.

Comment: maybe you could expand on the 99% by including some examples of what you found?

Comment: I started out using the PECL oauth extension, but I have not settled on this-> https://github.com/demogar/tmhOAuth-codeigniter
an adapted library for CI originality written by https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

Comment: I found that many OAuth server implementations have nuances that make it very hard to use a standard library.  I'd almost always recommend going with the SDK written for the platform with which you're interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with [OAuth-PHP](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) to write both a provider and client.

Documentation is unpolished, but the client code in the examples and the wiki is easy to reason about. The functions correspond well to the various OAuth actions (*"fetch resource X with my credentials using GET method"*). And it even provides a range of data stores, so it does all the hard work of persisting stuff. I used the session store for client-side and MySQL store for server.